# Pullback of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $V_1, V_2$ be a finitely generated integral normal proper scheme over a field $k$. Let $f : V_1 → V_2$ be a surjective morphism.

I encountered the definition of divisors:
For a prime divisor $W$ of $V_2$, and a prime divisor $W' = \overline{\{w'\}}$ of $V_1$ such that $W'$ is a irreducible component of $f^{-1}(W)$.
Let $I$ be the ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{V2, f(w')}$ and there is a positive integer $e'$ with $I\mathcal{O}_{V_1, w'} = \mathcal{m}_{w'}^{e'}$ (Note that $\mathcal{O}_{V_1, w'}$ is a DVR). Now define $f^{*} W = \Sigma e'W'$.

What I am having trouble with is showing $f^*(\phi) = (f^\sharp(\phi))$ for a rational function $\phi \in R(V_2)$.

Locally this statement is interpreted to the following statement:

Let $f: (A, \mathcal{m}) \rightarrow (B, \mathcal{n})$ be an injective local ring homomorphism with $B$ a DVR, $A$ normal Noetherian ring. For a prime ideal $\mathcal{p}$ of $A$ of height 1, define $e(\mathcal{p})$ by $\mathcal{p}B = \mathcal{n}^{e(\mathcal{p})}$. Then for $\phi \in Q(A)^*$ we have

$\operatorname{ord}_B f(\alpha) = \Sigma e(\mathcal{p}) \operatorname{ord}_{A_{\mathcal{p}}} \alpha$

where 'ord' is the valuation.

I have no idea how to prove or disprove this (probably the interpretation to the local is wrong?). When $A$ is a UFD or DVR it seems to be obvious but it does not apply to the general situation.

Comment: Isn't a normal, local, noetherian domain, of dimension 1 a DVR?

Comment: How to know dim A = 1?

Comment: I didnt meant that $A$ is 1 dimensionnal, but the localisations $A_p$ are, for $p$ the ideals defining the irreducible components mapping dominantly to your hyper surfaces.

Comment: I understand that, but how to know the sum of $e(p) \operatorname{ord}_{A_p} \alpha$ where $p$ range over such prime ideals when $A$ is just a normal ring?